# CSVPrinter java

Tags: java, csv

I'm currently using org.apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter to create a CSV File in my project.
When I started a new project and aimed to reuse this code:

```java
BufferedWriter successWriter = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(successFile + "_" + sDate + ".csv"));

csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(successWriter, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withDelimiter(delimiter.charAt(0))
                        .withRecordSeparator("\n").withEscape('\\').withQuoteMode(QuoteMode.NONE));
```

I get the warning that all "with*" methods are deprecated.

Apache states to use "set*" instead. But since these are CSVBuilder methods, I'm not sure how to use them properly.

Can you provide an example on how to use them best with the given code?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the javadoc (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/index.html)

DEFAULT is a CSVFormat instance with predefined builder in it.
You can update the builder or create one from scratch.

Here is a quick example :

```
 BufferedWriter successWriter = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get( "C:\\temp\\testingtest.csv"));
    char delimiter = ';';
    CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(successWriter, 
    // Creates a new default builder.
    CSVFormat.Builder.create()
    // use setters
    .setDelimiter(delimiter).setRecordSeparator("\n").setEscape('\\').setQuoteMode(QuoteMode.NONE).setHeader("h1","h2").build());
    csvPrinter.printRecord("1", "2");
    csvPrinter.flush();
```

**NB : apache commons-csv 1.9 which is the last version is marked with  vulnerabilities from dependencies:**

**1. CVE-2022-23221**
**2. CVE-2021-42392**
**3. CVE-2021-23463**

**you may not want to use it in production.**

Comment: Hi,
many thanks :) 

What would you reccoment using in prod instead?

Comment: OpenCSV could be a replacement, it's quite similar to commons-csv but with a bit more features :)

Comment: For everyone concerned about the vulnaribility - it comes from h2db and shown as test dependency on maven central repositories.